# why does my selector doesn't find my class?

Tags: jquery

My goal is to remove an image by clicking it.

I have this js:

```
    $('.imageSelected').on('click', function (event)
    {
        console.log('ok');
        $this.remove();
    });
```

And this html :

```
<li class="imageSelected">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="img-container" style="background-image:url({{ asset('bundles/mybundle/images/neige.jpg') }});">
     <div></div>
    </div>
  </a>   
</li>
```

But it never enters in my js, have any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your elements are dynamically generated. You may need event delegation. Try like following.

```
$(document).on('click', '.imageSelected', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$(this)` or `this` to get the currently clicked item.

```
$(function(){

   $('.imageSelected').on('click', function (event){
        $(this).remove();
        // or this.remove();
    });

});
```

[Here](http://%20$(this).remove();) is a working sample.

When writing jQuery code, the value of `this` or `$(this)` variable will change based on the context/scope of your code. So it is always a good idea to assign your this to a local variable and use that for further things.

Example.

```
$(function(){

   $('.imageSelected').on('click', function (event){
        var _this=$(this);
        //Use _this as needed
        _this.css( { color : 'red' });

        $.post("UrlToDelete", { id :"someIdFromCurrentElement",function(res) {
                _this.fadeOut(100,function(){
                    _this.remove();
                });
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: I don't think `this.remove()` is valid too. Is it?

Comment: Yes, it is just a typo I forgot it, but the fact is, any console.log() show up, or any errors.

Comment: `this` will return the HTML element and `$(this)` will return the jQuery wrapped version of `this`. For removing both will work in his usecase (`this.remove()`). For further operations, we should generally use `$(this)` which is the jQuery wrapped version of the object.

Answer (score 2):

As currently defined here, the `$this` is a new variable, which is undefined. You must use `this` to go to the current element. So, if you wanna use jQuery functions on them, you can wrap it like `$(this)`.

Your solution would be:

```
$('.imageSelected').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log('ok');
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it is just a typo I forgot it, but the fact is, any console.log() show up, or any errors, so it never enters in the event.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code which has an javascript error which prevents you to display alert or run jquery further. However the issue in your code is *$this* instead the correct form of using it here is *$(this)* which resolves the issue. I have added modified code in the fiddle, So take a look at your code here.

```
*https://jsfiddle.net/raghucse2010/c4jjzhvw/7/*
```